# SQL Find Oldest Car In Stock

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok i have the following tables and fields:

```
cars(carReg,regYear,Model,Manufacturer)
manufacturers (manufacturerId, Name, Country, Contat)
```

How would i get a Select statement to find the oldest car that is in stock from "Ford" as a manufacturer for example?

Comment: Have you already tried to query your database for this information? If so, show us the query that you have come up with so far.

Comment: Order by age, limit 1.

Comment: How does cars relate to manufacturers? What are the keys to the tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
select cars.*
from cars
join manufacturers on manufacturers.manufacturerId = cars.manufacturer
where manufacturers.Name = 'Ford'
order by cars.regYear asc
limit 1
```

Comment: what is the c. and m ?

Comment: Alias names for `cars` and `manufacturers` to make the query shorter.

Comment: how could i do it with out these as i dont undertand them

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: How would i List the Models of every Car from ford for example using sub queries

Comment: Ask another question about it.